Smartmicro radar ROS2 package Ethernet trouble
I'm working with a UMRR-96 Type 153 radar. I am having trouble using its ROS Package.
My hardware is good since there are no problems when I use the radar with its own application. It works with both Ethernet and CANBus connection.
However, when using the ROS2 package, the radar works with CANBus, but not with Ethernet. When I try to run the radar with Ethernet, I get the error:
user@OptiPlex-9020:~/radar$ ros2 launch umrr_ros2_driver radar.launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/user/.ros/log/2024-04-15-15-04-03-424555-OptiPlex-9020-23484
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1]: process started with pid [23486]
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1] [INFO] [1713182643.547335611] [smart_radar]: Updating ADAPTER params.
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1] [INFO] [1713182643.547555758] [smart_radar]: Updating ADAPTER params.
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1] [INFO] [1713182643.547583819] [smart_radar]: Updating SENSOR params.
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1] [INFO] [1713182643.547677170] [smart_radar]: Updating SENSOR params.
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1]   what():  Initialization failed
[ERROR] [smartmicro_radar_node_exe-1]: process has died [pid 23486, exit code -6, cmd '/home/user/radar/install/umrr_ros2_driver/lib/umrr_ros2_driver/smartmicro_radar_node_exe --ros-args -r __node:=smart_radar --params-file /home/user/radar/install/umrr_ros2_driver/share/umrr_ros2_driver/param/radar.params.template.yaml'].

Here is my config file:
/smart_radar:
  ros__parameters:
    adapters:
      adapter_0:
        hw_dev_id: 3
        hw_iface_name: eth0
        hw_type: eth
        port: 55555
    master_data_serial_type: port_based
    master_inst_serial_type: port_based
    sensors:
      # As many as 10 sensors all named as "sensor_<number>" in increasing order of numbers,
      # e.g., sensor_0, sensor_1, etc. The list must start with sensor_0.
      # For sensor `model`if using :
      # can: 'umrra4_can_v1_0_1', 'umrr96_can', 'umrr11_can', 'umrr9d_can_v1_0_3', 'umrr9d_can_v1_2_2', 'umrr9f_can_v2_1_1', 'umrr9f_can_v2_2_1'
      # port: 'umrra4_v1_0_1', 'umrr96', 'umrr11', 'umrr9d_v1_0_3', 'umrr9d_v1_2_2', 'umrr9f_v1_1_1', 'umrr9f_v2_1_1', 'umrr9f_v2_2_1'
      sensor_0:
        link_type: "eth"
        # The model of the connected sensor.
        model: "umrr96"
        # Adapter id to which sensor is connected
        dev_id: 3
        # The client_id of the sensor/source, must be a unique integer.
        id: 200
        # The ip address of the sensor or of the source acting as a sensor.
        ip: "192.168.11.11"
        # The port to be used.
        port: 55555
        # The frame_id to be set to the published messages.
        frame_id: "umrr"
        # Specify the history size.
        history_size: 10
        inst_type: "port_based"
        data_type: "port_based"
        # The interface name of the sensor
        uifname: "umrr96_t153_automotive"
        # The major version of the interface
        uifmajorv: 1
        # The minor version of the interface
        uifminorv: 2
        # The pathc version of the interface
        uifpatchv: 2

I am using ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04

The exception is only triggered in the event of problems with communication:
// Getting the communication services
m_services = CommunicationServicesIface::Get();
if (!m_services->Init()) {
  throw std::runtime_error("Initialization failed");
}

Looking at your configuration file I see that you define hw_iface_name: eth0 which isn't correct for systems using systemd (here: Ubuntu), as the interface names are named as follows enp<...>.
Verify whether the hw_iface_name configuration value matches the correct network interface name from the ip address command.
